# Update Parent Scope Variable Without Passing By Reference

Tags: function, powershell, variables, scope, pass-by-reference

I'm currently working on a PowerShell module, and I've come across something rather unusual that I cannot figure out how to duplicate. I'm using a module from Az PowerShell 3.2.0 as a reference.

I have the following example from Microsoft's Az.Dns Module:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dns/Add-AzDnsRecordConfig

```
$RecordSet = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -Name www -RecordType A -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -ZoneName myzone.com
Add-AzDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $RecordSet -Ipv4Address 1.2.3.4
Set-AzDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $RecordSet
```

The $RecordSet variable is being set locally, passed as a parameter to the Add-AzDnsRecordConfig command of this module, and the value of the $RecordSet local variable is then being automatically updated. When this variable is passed to the Set-AzDnsRecordSet command as a parameter, it contains the updated value it was assigned and not its initial value. Note that there is no additional assignment statement of the return value of Add-AzDnsRecordConfig.

How is this possible?

I know that I can define a function parameter as type `[ref]` or `System.Management.Automation.PSReference` and then pass by reference when it is called as `function -param ([ref]$myVariable)`. I can then update the value using `$myVariable.Value`, but that is **not** what is happening here. Somehow, this variable is being passed by value, and the value is being updated back in the local scope as if it were passed by reference.

Changing the name of the local variable also does not break this functionality. I've also done a `Show-Command -Name Add-AzDnsRecordConfig` and I can confirm that the type is not `System.Management.Automation.PSReference`.

I have a need to duplicate this functionality as closely as possible, as I am building a wrapper of sorts around this, but I am not sure how Microsoft is making this magic happen within this command.

Comment: [Variables of object types are automatically passed by reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

@zett42 Thank you for the concise answer. I definitely over-complicated this, and I did not realize that objects were automatically passed by reference without the need to specify it. As it turns out, I can simply reference the parameter within the function as `$RecordSet.Property = "New Value"`.

Back in the local scope, that does update the initially defined variable.

https://johnfabry.azurewebsites.net/2015/06/26/powershell-reference-types-and-value-types/
This article also helped me to understand how this works.